# How to split an array into multiple arrays with condition in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I have an array like below. What I want to know is: how to split that array into multiple sub-arrays when the value satisfies a condition? For example, if the next value difference exceeds 9, it will automatically create a new array. Here is a sample code.

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,25,26,27,28,29,50]
        
// Expected result = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], [25,26,27,28,29], [50]]
```

I've tried using `array.reduce()` but it doesn't work or I haven't found the right way.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mre] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're trying to achieve:

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,25,26,27,28,29,50];
cont DIFF = 9;

const result = arr.reduce((acc, val) => {
    if (acc.length === 0 || Math.abs(acc.at(-1).at(-1) - val) > DIFF) {
        acc.push([val]);
    } else {
        acc.at(-1).push(val);
    }
    return acc;
}, [])

console.log(result);
```

Where `array.at(-1)` returns the last element ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at)) and `[]` is the initial value of the reduce function ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)).

Answer (score 1):

Hope this answer will help. I used **array.slice()** method.

read more about **slice()** method  [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```
// array initialization
const arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,25,26,27,28,29,50];


/* function which will receive an array(arr) and the difference(diff) so that 
when the difference between two values at consecutive indexes(ex: arr[1] and arr[2]) exceeds the diff, we will create new array.
*/

const findSubArrays=(arr,diff)=>{
    let newArray=[];
    let startIndex=0;
    for(let i=0;i<=arr.length;i++){
         let nextIndex=i+1;
         if(arr[nextIndex]-arr[i]>diff){
            newArray.push([...arr.slice(startIndex,i)]);
            startIndex=i;
         }
     }
    return newArray;
}

const result=findSubArrays(arr,9);


console.log(result);//prints [ [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ], [ 8, 25, 26, 27, 28 ],[50] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.forEach()` and `Array.prototype.slice()` like so:

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,25,26,27,28,29,50]

const newArr = [];
let fromIndex = 0;
arr.forEach((num, i) => {
  if(arr[i + 1] - num > 9) {
    newArr.push(arr.slice(fromIndex, i + 1));
    fromIndex = i + 1;
  }
});
newArr.push(arr.slice(fromIndex));

console.log(newArr);
```